# SchemaEditor error when trying runserver

Tags: django, django-mongodb-engine

I have a MongoDB backend and am running into this error upon `python3 manage.py runserver`.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "hct/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "hct/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
>       self.check_migrations()
>     File "hct/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 164, in check_migrations
>       executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
>     File "hct.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in **init**
>       self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
>     File "hct/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in **init**
>       self.build_graph()
>     File "hct/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 182, in build_graph
>       self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
>     File "hct/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
>       self.ensure_schema()
>     File "hct/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
>       with self.connection.schema_editor() as editor:
>     File "hct/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 503, in schema_editor
>       'The SchemaEditorClass attribute of this database wrapper is still None')
>   NotImplementedError: The SchemaEditorClass attribute of this database wrapper is still None

I've made just the following changes in settings.py -

In installed apps, added

> 'djangotoolbox',

db configuration in settings.py -

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
    'NAME': 'dbname',
    'HOST': 'dbhost',
    'USER': 'dbuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'dbpw'
}
```

}

I have the following 3 mongodb packages installed in site-packages

- django-mongodb-engine (from https://github.com/django-nonrel)
- djangotoolbox
- pymongo

In case the following are relevant,

- My models.py isn't fully populated yet.
- If I run `django-admin runserver --settings = myproject.settings`, it raises

> ImportError: No module named 'myproject'

Project folder is as follows-

myproject

- myproject

  - settings.py
  - wsgi.py
- myapp

  manage.py

I'm not sure if I need to install any other package from https://github.com/django-nonrel (in addition to mongodb-engine-master)

Comment: this may solve the problem entirely, or it may at least get you past the ImportError ... you should have an empty file called __init__.py in your myproject/myproject directory.  (Also... what do you get if you do python3 manage.py shell (which in theory has fewer moving parts than runserver)

Comment: It has an __init__.py file (I had omitted it in the question). `python3 manage.py shell` runs w/o any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Uninstall django and install django-nonrel from https://github.com/django-nonrel/django.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was not in the virtual environment. Just in case some one gets a similiar error,

Go to virtualenv and retry.